# Как получить значение переменной, которое получаем во время выполнения события

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Здравствуйте. Я использую AForge framework для захвата изображений с камеры. Захват происходит во время выполнения события. Но к тому моменту, как выполняется метод AcceptTcpClientAsync переменная video(bitmap картинка) ещё null. Как сделать что бы событие выполнялось до метода AcceptTcpClientAsync? Далее bitmap переменная нужна в методе CodingImages

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartCapture();
            Form1 async = new Form1(51510);
            async.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
public void StartCapture()
        {
            VidoeCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VidoeCaptureDevices[0].MonikerString);
            FinalVideo.VideoResolution = FinalVideo.VideoCapabilities[2];
            FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            FinalVideo.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
        void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
public async void Start()
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(10000);
            IPAddress ipAddre = IPAddress.Loopback;
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddre, _listeningPort);
            listener.Start();
            LogMessage("Server is running");
            LogMessage("Listening on port " + _listeningPort);
        while (true)
 {
            //CaptureImageFromCamera captureFromCamera = new CaptureImageFromCamera();
            //Bitmap image = captureFromCamera.StartCapture();
            CodingImage img = new CodingImage();
            buffer = img.CodingImages(video);
            count = buffer.Length;
            lenght = buffer.Length.ToString();
            LogMessage("Waiting for connections...");
            try
            {
                var tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                HandleConnectionAsync(tcpClient);
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                LogMessage(exp.ToString());
            }
            i++;
        }

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно создать `TaskCompletionSource<>`, перевести его в выполненное состояние при получении кадра, и ожидать связанную задачу `tsc.Task` перед установлением соединений.

```
TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs;

// ...

void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    tcs.TrySetResult(true);
}

// ...

await tcs.Task;
CodingImage img = new CodingImage();
buffer = img.CodingImages(video);
count = buffer.Length;
lenght = buffer.Length.ToString();
LogMessage("Waiting for connections...");
try
{
    var tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    HandleConnectionAsync(tcpClient);
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    LogMessage(exp.ToString());
}
```

Кроме того, следует добавить синхронизацию доступа к полю `video`, т.к. может произойти переупорядочивание записи в него и вызова `tsc.TrySetResult()` с точки зрения потока, принимающего соединения.

Comment: хммм, если сделать так как вы предложили, то у меня валится эксепшн System.NullReferenceException. А вот про "синхронизацию доступа к полю" я не очень понял. Не могли бы вы пояснить?

Comment: Тут не телепаты, приведите полный стектрейс. Кроме того, вы часом не забываете создать экземпляр `TaskCompletitionSource`?

Comment: похоже, что забываю. А как это сделать?

Comment: Создать экземпляр типа. `tcs = new TaskCompletitionSource<bool>()`